# Error while using sklearn

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am trying to use sklearn in the following way for model prediction:

```
clf = MultinomialNB()

clf.fit(Xtrain,Ytrain)
Yans=clf.predict(Xtest)
```

But I am getting the following warning:

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/numpy/core/fromnumeric.py:2641: VisibleDeprecationWarning: `rank` is deprecated; use the `ndim` attribute or function instead. To find the rank of a matrix see `numpy.linalg.matrix_rank`.
  VisibleDeprecationWarning)
```

Because of this I am not getting the desired prediction. How can I fix this?

Comment: While this is not an error, but a warning (hence I don't understand why you don't get the desired output), you might try to downgrade your numpy installation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be an [issue](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/3866) with `scipy`. Try to upgrade it:

```
pip3 install --upgrade scipy
```